# Styling a polygon layer using external graphics

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a layer which is comprised of a number of different polygons symbolised according to their type.

I have set up a style which successfully filters by type then applies a corresponding fill (in some cases overlays this with a hatch style) and this works great.  Now I want to apply the same filters but in some instances apply an external graphic with a transparent background instead of a hatch style.

I have used the sld code found in the [Geoserver SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/index.html) and this works fine on its own but when I try and use it in conjunction with a filter it fails to work.

Has anyone come across this same issue and if so can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

There's an example of using an external graphic to fill a polygon at http://suite.opengeo.org/recipes/#sld/polygon/graphicfill

Basically it's:

```
<Rule>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <GraphicFill>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource
                  xlink:type="simple"
                  xlink:href="colorblocks.png" />
                <Format>image/png</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
            <Size>93</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicFill>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

Though that's from the SLD cookbook.  You can use a url in the xlink:href to refer to a graphic online, and I'm pretty sure it can be transparent.  If you post what you've tried then it'll be easier to help, everything should work with filters.